# Kendo : ComboBox in a grid - Sending additional data of selected combobox to combobox Read()

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET MVC5

I have a **combobox** in a **grid** (InLine Edit):

```
columns.Bound(x=>x.AccountID).EditorTemplateName("MyTemplate")
```

Where `MyTemplate` is in /Shared

There are millions of Accounts.

When I try to edit the **combo box in a grid** and choose a new value, the ID of the Account, not the name, appears. This is because of course the name of the account is not immediately present so in the Read().Data() of the **ComboBox.Datasource** I need to send **additional data**; the AccountID.

My ComboBox Template looks like this:

```
.DataSource(source=>
   source.Read(read =>
      read.Action("ReadAccounts".....)
         .Data("HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO SEND THE ACCOUNT ID AS EXTRA DATA 
             WHEN THIS CBO TEMPLATE IS IN A GRID")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the Combo Box defined in a partial view in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ComboBoxTemplate`

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
          .Name("AcctName")//must match Field Name that is being edited
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:250px" })
          .DataTextField("AcctName")
          .DataValueField("AcctCd")
          .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
          .AutoBind(true)
          .MinLength(3)
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetCombo", "GridPost").Data("OnAdditionalData");
              })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
          })          
)
```

Here's the view and controller action

```
columns.Bound(x => x.AcctName).Title("Acct Name").EditorTemplateName("ComboBoxTemplate");

 function OnAdditionalData() {          

            var entityGrid = $("#ProposalGridX").data("kendoGrid");
            var selected = entityGrid.dataItem(entityGrid.select());
            //if the id is off the Grid Row and not the ComboBox
            //select the row and pull the fields
            //selected.PropertyName

            return {
                text : $("#AcctName").data("kendoComboBox").text(),
                 val : $("#AcctName").data("kendoComboBox").value()
            };
        }

   public JsonResult GetCombo(string text, string val)
   {
         List<PortfolioViewModel> model = new AUMBusiness().GetAum(DateTime.Now);

           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
               model = model.Where(x => x.AcctName.StartsWith(text)).ToList();
            }

         return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Like with any Ajax calls, placing break points in the code might prevent the widget from performing as intended. For ex. using incell editing while clicking the Field to edit, if you place a breakpoint in `GetCombo` the ComboBox editor template will not default correctly to that value.

Comment: The issue is how to send the selected combobox's Value and Test to the .Data(). How do I get to them when they are in a Grid?

Comment: Have a look at my edit, it's basically copy pasted code from using a dropdown in an inline editor template, and capturing the change event to capture, ddlId and rowId. You should be able to make it work for your scenario

Comment: Don't know if this helps or not http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-add-combobox-to-editor-template-using-grid-pop-up

Comment: @Bahai, I revised my answer and posted all my relevant code. The combo box editor will be populated when entering edit mode as well as allow you to pass any fields/values along with the search text of the combobox.