# Kendo grid, dynamic dropdown as you type

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would to add dynamical filled dropdown select (or some other compoment) during the cell editation in Kendo Grid.

Type of the cell is a string and I would like to get responses from server as user is typing into cell.

Could somebody tell me how can i do it in right way or post here some useful tutorial?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: funny you mention that...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366108/kendo-combobox-in-a-grid-sending-additional-data-of-selected-combobox-to-com/26367440#26367440

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom editor for your cell like shown in this example
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom

They use a dropdown. In your case you will need a combobox or an autocomplete.
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/