# How can I jump to an item in a Kendo-UI dropdownlist by typing in a property other than the text-field?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a list of items in a dropdownlist.  Each item contains 3 properties.  The `name`, the `acronym`, and the `Id`.  I'm currently using the name and Id which works perfectly fine.

As the list is long, it's typical for a user to open the dropdownlist and start typing to find the item they are after.  Our users like to search/type the acronym, not the full name.  So because we only show the full name in the dropdown text, typing the acronym usually does not get you to the correct item.

How can I display the full name, but type-ahead on the acronym?

Here's the dropdown, pretty standard.

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list style="width: 500px" 
    class="ade-header-organization-list" 
    k-data-text-field="'organizationName'"
    k-data-value-field="'organizationId'" 
    ng-model="orgSelection"
    k-data-source="orgData">
</select>
```

The data looks like this (on a per record basis):

```
{ organizationId: 1, 
  organizationName: "Society of Kelvin-based Athletes in Tundra Environments", 
  orgAcronym: "SKATE"
}
```

I want to be able to typeahead the word "SKATE" and have it jump to the correct item.

Note that I'm using angular here, but the behavior isn't angular specific.

Comment: Can you please post some code? Are you using server filtering?

Comment: Actually as far as I understand you want to search (typeahead) by both the name and the acronym, right?

Comment: @OnaBai, that's correct.

Comment: @CSharper, added some code, though it's pretty simple.  No server side filtering, this is just a simple list that I want to be able to typeahead on.

Comment: I have this working using a comboBox, server side filtering and Razor View Engine. Which it seems neither you are using. I could still post it if you'd like to see it.

Comment: @CSharper, sure, that would be helpful!

Comment: It's actually very straightforward. Look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366108/kendo-combobox-in-a-grid-sending-additional-data-of-selected-combobox-to-com/26367440#26367440 . And the query I wrote in the controller, substitute it with this. `var acctNames = model.Where(x => x.AcctName.StartsWith(text)).ToList();
                model =  model.Where(x => x.AcctCd.StartsWith(text)).Concat(acctNames).ToList();`. Your just "Unioning" 2 queries one based off Name the other a Code