# Kendo ComboBox and passing additional data to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, combobox, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

So i have a ComboBox in a reusable partial view.  When i try to use getAddionalData and pass more parameters to the controller, is there a way i can pass the input of the combobox to the function?  I can't directly call the id of the combobox to get the value in the getAddionalData because there may be multiple and I won't know the exact id of which is calling the function.  I tried to use the 'this' qualifier in the function but that only gives me the url of the read.  For instance, on the dataBound function, i can call this.open() and it'll open my combobox.  I can't use that here.  Any idea? I looked into [Kendo : ComboBox in a grid - Sending additional data of selected combobox to combobox Read()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366108/kendo-combobox-in-a-grid-sending-additional-data-of-selected-combobox-to-com) and that didn't get me what i needed.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m=>m.Id)
                  .DataTextField("xxxx")
                  .DataValueField("xxxx")
                  .Placeholder("xxxx")
                  .MinLength(3)
                  .AutoBind(false)
                  .Events(e=>e.DataBound("functionCall").Change("functionCall"))
                  .TemplateId("templateId")
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%" })
                  .Filter("contains")
                  .Delay(500)
                  .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("method", "controller").Data("getAdditionalData(#=input.val()#)"))
                      .ServerFiltering(true))
                  .Height(500)

  )


var getAdditionalData = function (e) {
    //somehow get id of combobox calling the function and get the value of the input to pass to controller
    //can't use 'this' or e.sender
    return {
        text: value,
        searchLocation: "xxxx",
        searchType: "xxxx"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your `getAdditionalData()` function?

Comment: Are you trying to get the data of another combo box (or this one)?

Comment: This one, but trying to make it dynamic enough to where multiple combo boxes can call this one function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Telerik, http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-find-id-of-kendo-dropdownlist-in-event-handler, "The Kendo UI DataSource does not know anything about the widget, which is bound to ( including the id of the DropDownList widget)".  So it does not look like this is possible.